# Why does the name of the authors occur in uppercase in my references?

Tags: bibliographies

I want references in my article to be Surname, Forename{Initials}. Also with only the first letter of the surnames to be caps lock. I am running these commands but I do not get the desired format. How should I do it?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4 paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plaindin}
```

[image]

Comment: The format of the bibliography, including the author's names which are in small caps above, is determined by the bibliography style -- in this case, `plaindin`.

Comment: Then plz tell what bibliography style should I use?

Comment: This depends entirely on what format you want. I don't know of a good place to compare the different bibtex styles available - there are many. A quick search with google turned up [this page](http://www.reed.edu/cis/help/latex/bibtexstyles.html) that compares 7 styles.

Comment: Thanx! This is helpful.

Comment: Agog, a useful alternative is a command-line-based `makebst` that lets you customize the style. Of course, if you have the time to go through it.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the file `plaindin.bst` in the working directory as `plaindin-mod.bst` and, in this file, change the three occurrences of `\textsc` into `\textnormal`.

Then use `\bibliographystyle{plaindin-mod}` in your document.

You may also want to change the five occurrences of `<space>;` into `;` to avoid the wrong space before the semicolon.